# How to access data effectively in JSON PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

How do I get the data under `[t]`?

JSON data:

[image]

```
$array=  json_decode($json);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array[something blah blah]);
echo "</pre>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you convert the json object to an array, or access it as an object:

```
$json->manga[0]->t;
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. It solved my problem :D